# Docker NPM Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: docker, npm, nestjs

I'm trying to implement HMR in Nest in Docker.
Every time on start I get this error:

```
/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:433
    if (err) return callback(err);
    ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at /node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:433:5
    at eval (eval at create (/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
```

```
    npm version
    {
      api: '0.0.1',
      npm: '7.24.2',
      node: '14.18.1',
    }
```

My Dockerfile:

```
RUN npm install -g npm@7
RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
```

package.json:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^2.2.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "*",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/serve-static": "^3.0.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^9.0.1",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "nestjs-typeorm-paginate": "^4.0.2",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "pg": "^8.6.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
    "slugify": "^1.4.5",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.10",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^9.1.5",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^9.0.3",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^9.2.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.8",
    "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^3.0.7",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "^28.0.1",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "run-script-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "^28.0.8",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  },
  "main": "index.js"
```

I've already tried removing node_modules and reinstalling, and a different version of Node and npm. Any ideas?